# How to force Symfony 3 to use Memcached instead of Memcache class

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, symfony-3.2

I am running php7 on debian and I do only have the `php7-memcached` extension available since `php-memcache` appears to be deprecated or not compatible with php7.

When I run my Symfony 3.2.8 setup with composer some `post-install-cmd`'s are executed like

```
Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache
Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets
```

For some reason they require the memcache extension instead of the memcached extension which is installed and loaded with the php cli. So the execution results in the follow error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
Class 'Memcache' not found


Script Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\Composer\ScriptHandler::installAssets handling the symfony-scripts event terminated with an exception


[RuntimeException]
An error occurred when executing the "'assets:install --symlink --relative '\''web'\'''" command:

    [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
    Class 'Memcache' not found
```

Is there any way to make Symfony use the `Memcached` class of the available extension instead of the `Memcache` class? I've checked some app configurations which specify `Memcache` as class and modified them to `Memcached` without success. I couldn't find a configuration which might be related to the Debug Component specified in the exception.

Comment: Update to 3.3? https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-3-memcached-cache-adapter Sorry, not familiar enough with symfony.

Comment: By default Symfony does not require any external tools like Redis, Memcached or mentioned Memcache. Probably you just misconfigured something or installed bundle what requires Memcache (or use its by default). Try to use command `'assets:install --symlink --relative '\''web'\'''` with `-vvv` and check what happens in stack trace.